# Converting Python Dictionary to JSON Array

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I currently have a Python Dictionary that looks something like this:

```
OrderedDict([('2017-07-24', 149.7619), ('2017-07-25', 150.4019), ('2017-07-26', 151.1109), ...
```

that I am converting to JSON like so:

```
one_yr = json.dumps(priceDict)
```

Currently I am adding values to the dictionary from an SQL query by looping through it like so:

```
for i in query:
    date = i[0] 
    close = i[1]
    priceDict[date] = close
```

The problem is that this returns a JSON object, that i then have to convert to a JSON array.

I am wondering if I can just convert my Python Dictionary to a JSON array directly? Thanks.

Comment: But this is a dict. A dict maps to an object. If you don't want an object, why are you passing a dict?

Answer (score 3):

```
json.dumps(list(priceDict.items()))
```

But why do you have an `OrderedDict` in first place? If you pass the same list you passed to `OrderedDict` to `json.dumps` it will generate your array:

```
json.dumps([('2017-07-24', 149.7619), ('2017-07-25', 150.4019),....])
```

No need for `OrderedDict` in this case

Comment: `TypeError: Object of type odict_items is not JSON serializable` ? `json.dumps(list(price_dict.items()))`?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I should have mentioned I am using a Highcharts (a javascript charting library), that depends on the data being in an array. Currently the data looks like so: `var one_yr = [["2017-07-24", 41.8175], ["2017-07-25", 41.9946], ...  ["2018-01-01", 42.6143]}` and isn't being plotted.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a Python Dictionary to JSON using the json.dumps() method.

`

```
import json 
from decimal import Decimal
d = {}
d["date"] = "2017-07-24"
d["quantity"] = "149.7619"
print json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False)
```

`

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to create a dict with only two values. IE: `[('close', 149.7619), ('date', '2017-07-24')]`, the problem is I am looping through a series of values.

Comment: @ng150716 you can keep on adding the values by`d["close"] = "149.7619,150.4019"`

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to serializing data and a bit rusty with Python over-all, how would that fit into for loop?

Comment: @ng150716their is no need of loop I guess `d[""] = ([('2017-07-24', 149.7619), ('2017-07-25', 150.4019), ('2017-07-26', 151.1109,...)]) 
`this might help you

Comment: Sorry, i don't think I explained clearly what i mean't, but I have to loop through an SQL query to add the values to the dict. I have updated my post to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the OrderedDict but kept all the other data, I think I understand the request.  See if this works for you:

```
import json

my_dict = ([('2017-07-24', 149.7619), ('2017-07-25', 150.4019), ('2017-07-26', 151.1109)])

print(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, this still seems to create an object not an array (the data is still encapuslated in curly braces `{ ... }` as opposed to brackets `[ ... ]`