# Iterate parts of results to build JSON with no lists

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm building a spider with Scrapy - and obviously my Python-skills are lacking.

I'd like to build a JSON completely free of lists, but since the page I'm scraping has several "room types" for one single "room name" - I end up with lists.

Now this code ...:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for romtyper in response.selector.xpath(".//div[@class='room__collapsable']"):
            fradato = romtyper.xpath("//input[@type='hidden' and @name='fromDate']/@value").extract_first()
            personer = romtyper.xpath("//*[@id='booking-widget-guest-count-hotelnav-widget']/span/ng-pluralize/text()").extract_first()
            romnavn = romtyper.xpath(".//h2[@class='room__heading-level1']/text()[1]").extract_first()

            for prisboks in response.selector.xpath(".//div[@class='room__rates l-price-box l-price-box--selectable']"):
                romtype = prisboks.xpath(".//h3[@class='room-price-info__rate']/text()").extract_first()
                rompris = prisboks.xpath(".//span[@class='price']/text()").extract_first()
                yield {"fradato": fradato, "personer": personer, "romnavn": romnavn, "romtype": romtype, "rompris": rompris}
```

... provides me with only one of the room types (and prices). And if I swop to extract() instead of extract_first() in line -1 and -2 (from the bottom that is) - I get the lists again.

This is the result I'm looking for:

```
[
{"fradato": "2018-12-03", "personer": "1 Voksen", "romnavn": "A room name", "romtype": "Room type A", "rompris": "1088 "}, 
{"fradato": "2018-12-03", "personer": "1 Voksen", "romnavn": "A room name", "romtype": "Room type B", "rompris": "1288 "}]
```

Thanks for helping a noob out with basics ...

Comment: Can you show page html, please?

Comment: One advice will be to make dictionary out of your elements and then convert it to json. For reference, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51526076/converting-python-dictionary-to-json-array

Comment: not sure what you want? whats results are you getting now? please show us... are you outputting results using Python FEED? like `scrapy crawl spider -o test.json`??? or where do you want results?

Comment: HTML here --> [link](https://www.scandichotels.no/hotelreservation/select-rate?hotel=389&fromDate=2018-11-15&toDate=2018-11-16&room%5b0%5d.adults=2&bookingCode=) and the results I'm getting here --> [link](http://sandkassa.ddns.net/spiders/scandic.json) Yes, outputing just like you're suggesting, Umair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def parse(self, response):
     formsel = response.css('form[name=bookingWidget]')
     fradato = formsel.css('input[name=fromDate]::attr(value)').get()
     personer = formsel.css('input[name="room[0].adults"]::attr(value)').get()
     for room in response.css('div.room__collapsable'):
        romnavn = room.css('h2::text').get()
        for prisboks in room.css('div.room-price-info '):
            romtype = prisboks.css('h3::text').get()
            rompris = prisboks.css('span.price::text').get()
            if not romtype or not rompris:
                continue
            yield {"fradato": fradato, "personer": personer, "romnavn": romnavn, "romtype": romtype, "rompris": rompris}
```

Comment: THANKS! That sure did work. I've not yet had time to analyze your  solution (but I absolutely will) - but can I ask you prefer css vs xpath? @Elena Sh.

Comment: You want me to rewrite my solution? I think css is shorter and more friendly to read.

Comment: No - your solution is just fine Elena :-). I'm sure could handle that myself if I wanted to. I was just curious. I agree that it's easier to read. Thanks again!!

Comment: I tried to restructure a little bit to fit into my MongoDb, but for some reason this code only provides the last item in the "room" and the last item in the "prisboks". Do you see an obvious error? --> [link](http://sandkassa.ddns.net/example.html) @Elena

Comment: Yes, your `yield item` is outside of proper cycle @Jonas__G

Comment: Ah. Sometimes I just want to kill myself. Thanks for putting up with me, @Elena ... Have an excellent day!